# find range for dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, independence

> There are three vector $a$, $b$, $c$ in three-dimensional real vector space, and the inner product between them $a\cdot a=b\cdot b = a\cdot c= 1, a\cdot b= 0, c\cdot c= 4$. When setting $x = b\cdot c$, answer the following question: when $a, b, c$ are linearly dependent, find all possible values ​of $x$.
>   (dot here means dot product)

For dependent condition

$$\begin{align}
(a×b)·c &= 0\\
a·(b×c) &= 0\\
a(bc \sin θ)&=0
\end{align}$$

So $\theta = 0, \pi$.

Then
$$\begin{align}
x&=|b||c| \cos \theta \\
x&=2 \cos \theta \\
\implies x &= 2 \cos 0, x = 2 \cos \pi \\
x &= \mp 2
\end{align}$$

Am I right using triple cross product? or should i find $\theta$?
[image]

Comment: How did you get "$a(bc\sin\theta)=0$"?? That's wrong, because it doesn't follow from the previous line at all.

Comment: @zipirovich yes i was completely wrong, is my vector picture right? how can i observe the angle between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear dependence places the vectors in the same plane. This makes the problem easier because we can focus on the angle.

From $c\cdot c=4$ we get that $|c|=2$.

So $a\cdot c=2\cos\theta=1\implies\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\implies\theta=60^{\circ}$.

From $b\cdot b=1$ and $a\cdot b=0$ we get that $b$ is a unit vector perpendicular to $a$.

Since the angle between $a$ and $c$ is $60^{\circ}$, the angle between $b$ and $c$ is either $30^{\circ}$ or $150^{\circ}$.

Therefore, $x=2\cos{30^{\circ}}$ or $x=2\cos{150^{\circ}}$ so $x=\pm \sqrt{3}$

Comment: thankyou!! dependendence means in same plane, but can i write c as linear combination of a and b? and from $c.c=4$ , it imply that $c=2$?

Comment: $a\cdot c=2\cos\theta=1\implies\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\implies\theta=30^{\circ}$ , why is not $\theta=60$?

Comment: @fiksx I made a mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: @fiksx You don't need to consider a linear combination. We just use the fact that they are in the plane to reduce the problem to a 2D problem.

Comment: thanks!! but if use linear combination and think that c is in the span of a and b, is it right? and why angle between b and c $150^{\circ}$ ?

Comment: @fiksx It's easier to see if you draw the vectors in a plane. The angle between $a$ and $b$ is $90^{\circ}$ and the angle between $a$ and $c$ is $60^{\circ}$. That $60^{\circ}$ angle can be toward $b$ or away from it. If it is toward $b$ it is $90-60=30$ and if it is away it is $90+60=150$.

Comment: sorry wrong again, $\vec c=(1,\sqrt 3,0)$

Comment: if i chose $a =(1,0,0),b =(0,1,0),c =(1,+/- \sqrt 3,0)$, i added picture. is it because the coordinate c ? thats why the angle 150?

Comment: @fiksx You have two vectors $a$ and $b$ in a plane that are perpendicular. You add a third vector $c$ that makes an angle of $60^{\circ}$ with $a$. That $60^{\circ}$ angle can be in one of two places. One location makes an acute angle with $b$ and the other makes an obtuse angle.

Comment: oh i got it!!!! thankyou so much!! in this problem, the important part is a.b=0 so it is orthogonal to each other and a.a=1 and b.b=1 imply a and b orthonormal because unit length, am i right?

Comment: @fiksx Yes, you are correct. I respect the amount of work you put into this. Keep it up.

Comment: thankyou so much for the help!!!!! learn so much from your answer!! :D

Answer (score 0):

For the first identity, $a \times b$ is orthogonal to both $a,b$, hence $c$ must be in the plane spanned by the orthonormal $a,b$.

So we can write $c$ as 
$$
c = \alpha a + \beta b
$$

plugging this in we see that
$$
1 = a \cdot c = \alpha a \cdot a = \alpha
$$

and 
$$
x = b \cdot c = \beta b \cdot b = \beta 
$$

hence the norm squared of $c$ is
$$
c\cdot c = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1 + x^2 = 4
$$

this gives
$$
x = \pm \sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: thanks!! is this mean that a.b=0 so it is orthogonal to each other and span the plane? while c is linear combination of a and b so, you wrote$c = \alpha a + \beta b$ ?

Comment: The equation $x^2=3$ has **TWO** roots.

Comment: yep, bad misstake by me